# What are the properties and characteristics of a single Quantum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In [Quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics) , a [quantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum)  of energy called **Quanta** is origin of everything.

> In physics, a quantum (plural: quanta) is the minimum amount of any physical entity involved in an interaction.

$E=n.h.\nu$

$\epsilon=h.\nu$.

But it's properties and characteristics is unknown

What is properties and characteristics of a single Quanta?

Comment: One quantum, multiple quanta.

Comment: from the Webster dicitonary, definition of "plural":1
: of, relating to, or constituting a class of grammatical forms usually used to denote more than one or in some languages more than two . (plural: quanta means that if you have got more than one quantum, say two, you do not say you have "two quantums", you say you have "two quanta". A (one) quantum of energy  in quantum mechanics is called "quantum"

Answer (score 4):

The question  confuses the concept of quantization with the "origin of everything", whatever that last is.

Starting from the beginning:

There exists classical mechanics, studied over the last centuries with explicit and well know differential equations whose solutions are used in all engineering problems around us.

The solutions are continuous functions of the variables.

There exist wave mechanics of continuous media and of electromagnetic potentials, again governed by well known differential equations whose solutions are in use in the technology around us.

These equations have some solutions which are quantized in some variables. For example the well tuned violin string of a sharp frequency, or monochromatic light.

The quanta of quantum mechanics are one level below the two above formulations. Definitive experiments and data gathered pointed the way to the quantized nature of matter and radiation at a very basic lower level. From the  periodicity of the [periodic table of elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_elements) , the [photoelectric effect,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect)  and innumerable studies over the years it is established that  quantum mechanical equations hold in the microcosm, and that nature macroscopically emerges from an underlying quantum mechanical level.

This does not mean that there does not exist a continuum in some variables, it just means that specific solutions of QM equations have allowed values for the variables that are quantized, i.e. come in packets of energy or have specific locations in space ( cf crystals).

$\epsilon=h\nu$ allows all frequencies in free electromagnetic fields. Their creation and absorption happens in quanta specific to specific atoms and boundary conditions.

Thus the "origin of everything" is not a specific quantum of energy, but specific quantum mechanical equations whose solutions describe nature as sometimes having transitions in quantized steps and sometimes continuously.