# Isn't a single Quantum one single string?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, string-theory

In physics, [a quantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum) (plural: quanta) is the minimum amount of any physical entity involved in an interaction.
In Quantum Mechanics There is no difference between one Quantum to another one.

According to [string theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(physics)), absolutely everything in the universe—all of the particles that make up matter and forces—is comprised of tiny vibrating fundamental strings. Moreover, every one of these strings is identical.

The only difference between one string and another, whether it's a heavy particle that is part of an atom or a massless particle that carries light, is its resonant pattern, or how it vibrates.

> "how quanta of different particles are related to different vibration patterns of the corresponding excited string in string theory."

Isn't a single Quantum one single string?
if so, then how we can still say There is no difference between one Quantum to another one while there is one difference between one string and another, that is, its resonant pattern.

How exactly are the different motions of one kind of fundamental strings assumed to give rise to the spectrum of elementary particles we observe?

> I'm perty sure about a few things, first: according to experimental physics there is nothing more fundamental than a single quantum. second: according to Theoretical Physics there is nothing more fundamental than one single string. Third, it is possible that they both are one thing but there are a lot of misunderstanding with both of them. Fourth, if a quantum is not one single  string may itself prove a lack of strings.

Quantum Mechanics space-time is like waves caused by a lot of Quanta so bumpy and chaotic, maybe it is not waves, it's strings resonant pattern.

In one word i'm asking about possibility of **Quantum-String duality.**

[image: photo]

**Levels of magnification:**

1. Macroscopic level –Matter
2. Molecular level
3. Atomic level – Protons, neutrons, and electrons
4. Subatomic level – Electron
5. Subatomic level – Quarks
6. Quantum-String duality level

Comment: @dmckee This is NOT a doublicate of the question you linked to. It asks about how quanta of different particles are related to different vibration patterns of the corresponding excited string in string theory. Please, anybody should read the question carefully to see that it is NOT a doublicate but rather an interesting question. Please reopen this, dmckee you were way too fast and injodicious once more with closing :-(!

Comment: This question is constructed on the same misunderstanding as the linked one: that "a quanta" is a thing rather than a notation for the discreteness of some quantity under some circumstances, and it feels like Neo  I'm willing to be shown that I'm wrong about this, but I would like to be shown.

Comment: @dmckee elementary particles correspond to the quante of different quantum fields in QFT. This question now asks about how in ST the quanta of the different elementary particles are related to the particular excitations of only one single fundamental string. The question is very different from the other one. People in the know could give quite an interesting answer to this if you dont prevent it by leaving this questio closed ...

Comment: @Dmckee ... conserning quanta of angular momentum in ordinary QM asked about in the other question it is right that they are just a notion that something is discrete, but in QFT and ST the quanta are things, they are elementary (sometimes only virtual) particles. This second question is clearly about the this second notion of quanta. It is very unfair to close a rather theoretical question unilaterally without asking any other more theoretically inclined mod or other person for their opinion ...

Comment: @Dilaton In which case the field is the thing and the quantum is just an excitation number. It is never just "a quantum" is is always a quantum *of* soimething energy or magnetic field strength or whatever. Anna explained this in the last version.

Comment: @dmckee but this one is about the quanta of the elementary particles and how they are related to the motion or exitation of only one kind of fundamental string. It is a good question and it IS different from the one Anna answered. This question should really not be closed. I dont know why you cant see the difference between the two questions. The other one is a broad question about quanta in QM and this one is a specific ST question. I know that you dont particularly like ST, but this is no reason to close the question ...!

Comment: > **Possible related:**  
> [What are the properties and characteristics of a single Quantum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/what-are-the-properties-and-characteristics-of-a-single-quantum)

Comment: Neo, your question is ok, dmckee was wrong to close it. The other question is related but not a duplicate. I have escalatet the issue to [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2605/2751). That is all I can do since I have not the power to vote to reopen. My flag still waites to be reviewed. I hope all will be well as soon as David Zaslavski finds time to have a look at it ... :-/

Comment: Neo, maybe you can edit the title a it too, such that everybody can better see from afar what you are interested in.

Comment: @Dilaton you can edit it too, i'll review it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6446/discussion-between-dilaton-and-neo)

Comment: Neo I have given you some tips about how I would edit in chat, you can just follow the link in my above comment.

Comment: @Neo, the simple answer to the title question is "No". The "quantization" of strings has a third hand connection with the quantum of an energy exchange, or the quanta of other operator variables . Strings classically have various intrinsic resonances depending on their length. The strings in string theory also display this structure which has been identified, according to the quantum numbers of the levels, with the elementary particles of the standard model table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model,( a shorthand for all of the experimental elementary particle data).

Comment: @Neo the pattern arises because those dimension are chosen for the string theory where the standard model particles can be accomodated in the resonance pattern (symmetry groups)according to their quantum numbers. That is why we need ten dimensional strings at least, so that the groups describing the elementary particles can be accomodated.

Comment: @Dilaton FYI I did see this question early on. There are two reasons I haven't reopened it: (1) generally moderators do not override each others' actions, and (2) up until the last time I saw it, it also fell under NaRQ, and I don't care to open it and reclose it for a different reason that would give it an automatic downvote and remove a potentially useful related question link. In its current form, it is probably not NaRQ anymore but it is based on some deep misconceptions. [It's in the hands of the meta community now.](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/)

Comment: @dmckee, please reconsider your decision. This question now has 7 upvotes versus only 1 downvotes, 4 stars and at least one reopen vote. I would like to see Dilaton's answer which could be enlightening to me, at the very least. I am not a string theorist and would appreciate their view about this question.

Comment: @DavidZ If dmckee has made a mistake it should be undone. And FrankH is right, the question has so many upvotes and stars now. Leaving it closed is strongly against the will of the community. Moderatirs can make mistakes too. Dmckee often closes theoretical questions fast for no good reason, it is not the first time. Please David, I thought you at least are more reasonable. If dmckee does not admit his blatant mistake he has to be overruled. That is exactly why we dont have only one mod, in order to undo such mistakes. I am very disappointed.

Comment: If explicitely read somewhere there is a TEAM of moderators on the site to resolve for example such situations in which a moderator makes a mistake and wrongly acts against the will of the community.

Comment: @FrankH if you want the question to be reopened too, it would be helpful if you could post an answer to my [meta](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2605/2751) question corresponding to your above comment. David said it is in the hands of the meta community now.

Comment: Folks, I've been away fom my computer for more than twenty four hours on travel. I'll look at this again tomorrow. David  *did* look at it in it's original form and mbq has looked at it since then.

Comment: Neo, "duality" is a concept in theoretical particle physics that ties two theories as a different manifestation of the same basic theory. The term "quantum" , which , if you read my reply to your previous question and my comments above, should be clear, is a term describing the behavior of variables, expressed as operators under quantum mechanics. It is not an entity. A string, even a classical string, can contain quanta, but is is not a different manifestations of any type of quantum. It is a mathematical representation of a generic particle.

Comment: @Dilaton: if you want to convince someone - whether a moderator or simply a user who can cast a re-open vote - that re-opening is a good idea, make your argument on meta and let them read it. Calling someone unreasonable when you've put so little effort into your reasoning is unfair and counter-productive.

Comment: @dmckee in this case I have to apologize. I did not know that you are travelling and just thought you are ignoring (or dismissing by silence) everything that is said concerning this issue. So thanks for looking at it again.

Comment: @Shog9 yes ... But I have a question since you declined my flag: If I strongly disagree with a question being closed, I always try to first discuss it in the comments, then cast a flag to bring it to the attention of all mods, and if this does not help escalate it to meta to see what the community thinks about it. I can cast no reopen votes. Is this wrong then? I thought following this order of actions holds the big noise low as long as possible ... Anyway, everything now to do about this one, is to wait and see how it pans out on meta and what dmckee says if he looks at it again.

Comment: @Dilaton give me your answer to this question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44130/what-are-the-properties-and-characteristics-of-a-single-quantum)

Comment: You still have this basic misunderstanding *"according to experimental physics there is nothing more fundamental than a single quantum"* lying at the heart of this question. You've put that phrase in  block quote, but have not offered a citation for it, and in my view it is simply not the case.

Comment: There is the making of a useful question here as in *"How exactly are the different motions of one kind of fundamental strings assumed to give rise to the spectrum of elementary particles we observe?"*, which is a good question at the pop-sci level (have we done this yet?), but on the whole I think that question would be better served by starting over so that it is not associated with things like *"Quantum Mechanics space-time is like waves caused by a lot of Quanta so bumpy and chaotic, maybe it is not waves, it's strings resonant pattern"* which adds ideas not found elsewhere in the text.

Comment: @dilaton this question has gotten weirder and weirder. I recommend you give up on it, then YOU right a new question about how it is that different vibrations of one kind of string can give us the whole zoo of elementary particles with such different properties such as masseless photons, very heavy top quarks, electric charges, color charges, weak charges, spins, etc. I would like to know the answer to that at a pop-level. It is perfectly OK for you to write the question and to write an answer. Give up & make a new question so you can write the answer you so wanted to add to this question.

Comment: @dmckee Is there any reason that i should to answer to your question in your comment while you closed my question by no reason and also vote it down!?
the only thing that i can tell you is that, my researches are lightyears ahead of the world you live on it.
for someone like you, Construction may begin in 2015, commissioning in 2019 and initial preliminary results may be ready about 2020.